# Single Speed Freehub

Tags: hub, single-speed

I have a Road bike with a Shimano 8 Speed Freehub.

I want to go to a single speed bike, but I'd rather not use a fistfull of spacers.
Is anyone aware of a single speed freehub body that I can replace my Shimano freehub body with?

If it matters, Shimano freehubs are the lose ball bearing types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Single speed freehubs have totally different spacing so you have a less dished wheel. You'll have to use spacers.